# Исключить одинаковый текст между Edit

Tags: delphi

На форме расположено **17 Edit.text**. Есть ли варианты сделать код по компактней.
**Задача** - запретить ввод одинаковых символов в edit (Что бы текст в во всех edit разный). Если есть совпадения то вывести сообщение.

Я сделал вот такой код но хотелось бы как то по компактней.

```
if (Edit17.text = Edit1.text) 
or (Edit17.text = Edit2.text) 
or (Edit17.text = Edit3.text) 
or (Edit17.text = Edit4.text) 
or (Edit17.text = Edit5.text)
or (Edit17.text = Edit6.text) 
or (Edit17.text = Edit7.text)    
or (Edit17.text = Edit8.text)
or (Edit17.text = Edit9.text)
or (Edit17.text = Edit10.text)
or (Edit17.text = Edit11.text)
or (Edit17.text = Edit12.text)
or (Edit17.text = Edit13.text)
or (Edit17.text = Edit14.text)
or (Edit17.text = Edit15.text)
or (Edit17.text = Edit16.text)  
or (Edit1.text = Edit2.text) 
or (Edit1.text = Edit3.text) 
or (Edit1.text = Edit4.text) 
or (Edit1.text = Edit5.text)
or (Edit1.text = Edit6.text) 
or (Edit1.text = Edit7.text)     
or (Edit1.text = Edit8.text)
or (Edit1.text = Edit9.text)
or (Edit1.text = Edit10.text)
or (Edit1.text = Edit11.text)
or (Edit1.text = Edit12.text)
or (Edit1.text = Edit13.text)
or (Edit1.text = Edit14.text)
or (Edit1.text = Edit15.text)
or (Edit1.text = Edit16.text)   
or (Edit2.text = Edit3.text) 
or (Edit2.text = Edit4.text) 
or (Edit2.text = Edit5.text)
or (Edit2.text = Edit6.text) 
or (Edit2.text = Edit7.text)     
or (Edit2.text = Edit8.text)
or (Edit2.text = Edit9.text)
or (Edit2.text = Edit10.text)
or (Edit2.text = Edit11.text)
or (Edit2.text = Edit12.text)
or (Edit2.text = Edit13.text)
or (Edit2.text = Edit14.text)
or (Edit2.text = Edit15.text)
or (Edit2.text = Edit16.text)
or (Edit3.text = Edit4.text) 
or (Edit3.text = Edit5.text)
or (Edit3.text = Edit6.text) 
or (Edit3.text = Edit7.text)     
or (Edit3.text = Edit8.text)
or (Edit3.text = Edit9.text)
or (Edit3.text = Edit10.text)
or (Edit3.text = Edit11.text)
or (Edit3.text = Edit12.text)
or (Edit3.text = Edit13.text)
or (Edit3.text = Edit14.text)
or (Edit3.text = Edit15.text)
or (Edit3.text = Edit16.text)   
or (Edit4.text = Edit5.text)
or (Edit4.text = Edit6.text) 
or (Edit4.text = Edit7.text)     
or (Edit4.text = Edit8.text)
or (Edit4.text = Edit9.text)
or (Edit4.text = Edit10.text)
or (Edit4.text = Edit11.text)
or (Edit4.text = Edit12.text)
or (Edit4.text = Edit13.text)
or (Edit4.text = Edit14.text)
or (Edit4.text = Edit15.text)
or (Edit4.text = Edit16.text)   
or (Edit5.text = Edit6.text) 
or (Edit5.text = Edit7.text)     
or (Edit5.text = Edit8.text)
or (Edit5.text = Edit9.text)
or (Edit5.text = Edit10.text)
or (Edit5.text = Edit11.text)
or (Edit5.text = Edit12.text)
or (Edit5.text = Edit13.text)
or (Edit5.text = Edit14.text)
or (Edit5.text = Edit15.text)
or (Edit5.text = Edit16.text)   
or (Edit6.text = Edit7.text)     
or (Edit6.text = Edit8.text)
or (Edit6.text = Edit9.text)
or (Edit6.text = Edit10.text)
or (Edit6.text = Edit11.text)
or (Edit6.text = Edit12.text)
or (Edit6.text = Edit13.text)
or (Edit6.text = Edit14.text)
or (Edit6.text = Edit15.text)
or (Edit6.text = Edit16.text)   
or (Edit7.text = Edit8.text)
or (Edit7.text = Edit9.text)
or (Edit7.text = Edit10.text)
or (Edit7.text = Edit11.text)
or (Edit7.text = Edit12.text)
or (Edit7.text = Edit13.text)
or (Edit7.text = Edit14.text)
or (Edit7.text = Edit15.text)
or (Edit7.text = Edit16.text)   
or (Edit8.text = Edit9.text)
or (Edit8.text = Edit10.text)
or (Edit8.text = Edit11.text)
or (Edit8.text = Edit12.text)
or (Edit8.text = Edit13.text)
or (Edit8.text = Edit14.text)
or (Edit8.text = Edit15.text)
or (Edit8.text = Edit16.text)   
or (Edit9.text = Edit10.text)
or (Edit9.text = Edit11.text)
or (Edit9.text = Edit12.text)
or (Edit9.text = Edit13.text)
or (Edit9.text = Edit14.text)
or (Edit9.text = Edit15.text)
or (Edit9.text = Edit16.text)
or (Edit10.text = Edit11.text)
or (Edit10.text = Edit12.text)
or (Edit10.text = Edit13.text)
or (Edit10.text = Edit14.text)
or (Edit10.text = Edit15.text)
or (Edit10.text = Edit16.text)  
or (Edit11.text = Edit12.text)
or (Edit11.text = Edit13.text)
or (Edit11.text = Edit14.text)
or (Edit11.text = Edit15.text)
or (Edit11.text = Edit16.text)  
or (Edit12.text = Edit13.text)
or (Edit12.text = Edit14.text)
or (Edit12.text = Edit15.text)
or (Edit12.text = Edit16.text)  
or (Edit13.text = Edit14.text)
or (Edit13.text = Edit15.text)
or (Edit13.text = Edit16.text)  
or (Edit14.text = Edit15.text)
or (Edit14.text = Edit16.text)  
or (Edit15.text = Edit16.text)   then
begin
  ShowMessage('Текст во всех Edit должен быть разный - не должен совпадать!');
end;
```

Comment: ох, жесть какая.

убери все поля Edit в массив
и пробегай в цикле по этому массиву и делай проверки. То что сейчас, 
во-первых, не работает, во-вторых, на боевом коде за такое будут голову отгрызать.

Comment: Определенно: массив это наилучший выход в подобной ситуации.

Comment: @Dima, А как то в массиве сделать ? Хоть наводку дайте ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего - изменить интерфейс чтобы избавиться от такого внушительного количества компонентов, которые должны содержать уникальную информацию. С другой стороны, если это невозможно по каким-либо причинам, решение можно найти в виде создания массива (спасибо [Андрею Самолову](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/312760/%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%a1%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2) за подсказку!), в который помещается текст, содержащийся в компонентах, и с которым в последующем идет работа на предмет тестирования уникальности текста.

**Ответ был изменен!**

Примерный код представлен ниже.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  TextArray: Array of String;
  EditsAmount: Integer;
  Index: Integer;
  S: String;
  Found: Boolean;
  i: Integer;
begin
  EditsAmount := 6;

  SetLength(TextArray, EditsAmount);

  Index := 0;
  for i:=0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
    begin
      if Components[i] is TEdit then
        begin
          TextArray[Index] := TEdit(Components[i]).Text;
          Inc(Index);
        end;
    end;

  Found := false;
  Index := 0;
  repeat
    S := TextArray[Index];
    for i:=Low(TextArray) to High(TextArray) do
      begin
        if i = Index then
          Continue;

        if S = TextArray[i] then
          begin
            ShowMessage(Format('Равные строки найдены!' + #13#10 +
                               'Поле ввода №: ' + '%d' + #13#10 +
                               'Поле ввода №: ' + '%d', [Index, i]));
            Found := true;
            Break;
          end;
      end;

    if not Found then
      Inc(Index);
  until ((Index = High(TextArray)) or Found);
end;
```

Переменная `EditsAmount` отвечает за количество элементов массива. Так как у Вас фиксированное количество - можете установить эту переменную в значение `17`. Для своего теста я указал значение `6`.

Если нужна работа "на лету", то необходимо заполнение массива выполнять заранее (при показе формы, например). В отличие от предыдущей версии кода, текущая работает с массивом строк - нет нужды беспокоиться о невалидной ссылке на компонент при его удалении.

Потестировал на 6-ти компонентах `TEdit` - совпадения находит верно. Если найдете ошибку, недочет - укажите, я поправлю.

Comment: Вторая часть кода могла бы быть компактнее и проще - `for I := Low() to High() do for K := Low() to I - 1 do if not found then if TextArray[I] = TextArray[K] then begin ShowMessage(); found := True; end;`

Comment: @Kromster, Ваш вариант действительно короче и читабельнее, чем мой ;) Однако он продолжает поиск в массиве даже после того, как найдет совпадающие строки. Чтобы это исправить, понадобится ввести `Break` в цикле `for k...do` и проверку `if Found then Break` в цикле `for i...do`, что увеличит размер предложенного кода.

Comment: Проверка `if not found` находится во внутреннем цикле и не даст сообщению показаться более 1 раза. То что при нахождении повтора цикл `I` будет все равно повторяться до конца, на 17 элементах,  ничтожно.

Comment: @Kromster, да, сообщение показывается 1 раз, верно. Массив небольшой - тоже верно. Но если есть возможность избежать лишних итераций - почему бы и не?

Comment: Можно избежать итераций и способом который избрал ТС (т.е. развернуть все циклы в один огромный `if .. else if`). В данном случае компактность и простота кода достигается столь незначительным увеличением скорости проверки (причем если совпадений нет, то разницы по скорости даже не будет), что оно того более чем стоит.

Comment: @Kromster, по сравнению с решением ТСа, Ваш вариант безусловно компактнее, однако, я останусь при своем мнении ;)